# Go to another view (UIViewController) from within UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A newbie Objective C question. Im trying to programmaticly change view from another view. But I only succeed in activating the tab button in the tabbarcontroller.

In my ViewDidLoad I have a condition that if thats not met, load the second view instead.

Is there any kind soul that can help out a Objective-C beginner? I have googled and search stackoverflow for the answer but with no luck.

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

some variables

}

some @properties
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(condition is met) {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface otpAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>     {

UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *tabBarController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation otpAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBarController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];

return YES;
}
```

**Edit!**
I found a solution to my problem.

```
int selectedindex = 1;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = selectedindex;
UIViewController *tempvc = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:selectedindex];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:tempvc.view];
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Hei it is not the solution...Its just a work around.The code you had added to swap views must performed by tabbarcontroller...but you had done it in your code...

Comment: I removed [Solved] from the title. Do not add such labels because it will lessen the number of alternative solutions/answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the index for the `tabBarController` instance of the app delegate like `yourAppDelegate.tabBarController`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However i'm not sure how to do this :) Can explain a little bit more and perhaps provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tabBarController as IBOutlet , there is no need to allocate it in your app delegate. Please remove these code from your appDelegate method (application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)..

```
 tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```